# handle html objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have come across a problem trying to pass some objects to a java function. I am using a jquery .each loop. My code is as follows:

```
$('.overme').each(function () {
    grow($(this).parent().find("#txtInput"), $(this).parent().find("#txtInputa"));
...
```

The grow function is as follows:

```
function grow (one, two) {
    var colsDefault = one.cols;
    var rowsDefault = one.rows;
         colsDefault.style.width;
...
```

Unfortunately I am not getting any object data. Where i'm I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the html code - seems like you are not selecting the right item?

Comment: Functions are terminated with `}`, not `...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jquery Selector returns a Jquery Object and not the DOM-Element. If you want the element itself you can use

`$(this).parent().find("#txtInput")[0]`

Comment: Sorry i meant DOM-Object. The OP talked about "html objects"

Answer (score 3):

You are making several mistakes:

- *Java* is not *JavaScript* (you are passing this to JavaScript function),
- there are no *HTML objects* in this case, they are called *DOM elements*,
- you are not passing DOM elements, you are passing jQuery objects (they contain DOM elements),

If you want to access DOM element within jQuery object, you have two options:

```
jquery_object.get(0)
```

or

```
jquery_object[0]
```

so your solution could look like this:

```
function grow (one, two) {
    var colsDefault = one.get(0).cols;
    var rowsDefault = one.get(0).rows;
         colsDefault.style.width;
```

**EDIT:**

One additional mistake: you are iterating through the elements with `overme` class just to find something that is referred to by ID. Because IDs are unique, you are probably making a mistake of assigning the same ID to several elements, or by making it too complex where you can just refer to them by ID (eg. instead of `$(this).parent().find("#txtInput")` you can use `$("#txtInput")`). This can be justified only by the need to do different things regarding this single element with specified ID (`txtInput`) is within current element's parent or not.

If you now thing you do not need to check whether `#txtInput` is under current element's parent, your `grow()` call could be shortened a lot:

```
grow($("#txtInput"), $("#txtInputa"));
```

Also give us some HTML so we can check if some errors occuring within it may be interfering.